# Pygame Not Responding First Time

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, pygame

I'm just adding some finishing touches to my tank game, but there's this slight thing that's been bothering me. It's just that, at the menu screen, when the user presses a different set of keys to access different things such as the instruction screen, game screen, or custom username input screen, it takes two presses of the button to respond and not the desired one single press. Here's the little excerpt of code:

```
menu = True
instruct = False 
run = False 
name1 = False  
name2 = False     

while menu:
    pygame.event.get()
    theKey = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if theKey[pygame.K_RETURN]:
        menu = False
        run = False
        instruct = True
        name1 = False

    if theKey[pygame.K_LSHIFT] or theKey[pygame.K_RSHIFT]:
        menu = False
        run = True
        begin = time.time()

    if theKey[pygame.K_BACKSPACE]:
        menu = False
        run = False
        instruct = False
        name1 = True
        user_input = ''
    menu_screen()

FONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)  # A font object which allows you to render text.
BG_COLOR = pygame.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pygame.Color('dodgerblue1')
USEFONT = pygame.font.Font(None, 70)
yourText1 = "Player 1, Enter Your Name: "
yourText2 = "Player 2, Enter Your Name: "
userNamePrompt = USEFONT.render(yourText1, True, BLUE)    
userNamePrompt2 = USEFONT.render(yourText2, True, BLUE)    


while name1:
    theKey = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            name1 = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                user_input = user_input[:-1]
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                name1 = False 
                name2 = True
                user2_input = ''
            else:
                user_input += event.unicode

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    # Create the text surface.
    text = FONT.render(user_input, True, BLUE)
    # And blit it onto the screen.
    screen.blit(userNamePrompt, (20,20))
    screen.blit(text, (20, 300))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)



while name2:
    theKey = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            name1 = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                user2_input = user2_input[:-1]
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                name2 = False
                run = True
                begin = time.time()
            else:
                user2_input += event.unicode


    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    # Create the text surface.
    text = FONT.render(user2_input, True, BLUE)
    # And blit it onto the screen.
    screen.blit(userNamePrompt2, (20,20))
    screen.blit(text, (20, 300))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

playName1 = user_input
playName2 = user2_input

while instruct:
    pygame.event.get()
    theKey = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if theKey[pygame.K_BACKSPACE]:
        instruct = False
        run = False
        menu = True


    if theKey[pygame.K_LSHIFT] or theKey[pygame.K_RSHIFT]:
        instruct = False
        run = True
        begin = time.time()
    instruct_screen()
```

In this case, the code takes two taps of the "return" or enter button to get the instruction screen and two taps of the shift key to show the game screen - and I've tried to fix it, but to no avail. Does anyone know why this may be occurring and what/how the code needs to be modified in order for it to work as desired?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're calling `pygame.key.get_pressed()` twice, once in the menu loop and once in the name1 loop. Each time you call it, it's popping the keypress event off the stack, so the second time it will wait for a second keypress. You should store the result the first time, and use that in the second loop.